# How to config Nginx location?

Tags: nginx, location

I have a code in nginx.conf :

```
location ~ ^/(?!(confirm.html)) {
if ($http_cookie !~* "session") {
     set $block "true";
  }
if ($http_user_agent ~* (Google|google|Googlebot|Googlebot-Image|Google-Site-Verification|Google\ Web\ Preview|bing|Bing|Yahoo|yahoo)) {
      set $block "false";
}
if ($block = "true") {
    return 302 /confirm.html;
}
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
}
```

and I want add another code :

```
location /theme {
proxy_pass  http://localhost/theme;
}
```

but it doesn't work and I don't know how to solve it.
Who can help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem :

```
 location ~ ^/(?!(confirm.html|theme)) {
```